# In JPA, what benefit is there for "save" to return a new persistent instance for the case of updates?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I understand that merge is for updating an existing record, and persist is for inserting a new record.

When `save` is called for the case of update, we return the return value of calling `merge`.
But I don't understand why we would want a new persistent instance on merge. Wouldn't the instance you are merging and the instance that is returned contain the same values?

Comment: If you look at the documentation of [`EntityManager#merge(T)`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/entitymanager#merge(T)) (which I assume is what you're talking about), then you'll see it returns "_the managed instance that the state was merged to_". So, it may return a completely different instance. If you continue using the instance you passed as an argument, then you may be working with an _unmanaged_ instance.

Comment: that's exactly what i mean. My question is why would it return a different instance? Within `save` if you look at it's case for when it does `persist`, you'll see that it looks like so `if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) { em.persist(entity); return entity; }`. As in, it just returns the entity that's passed in. But for the case of merge it does this `return em.merge(entity);` First of all, I don't understand why `merge` would want to return a different instance in the first place

Comment: Because you're merging. You might be merging an unmanaged instance that already has a managed instance in the cache.

Comment: Sure but why can't the entity you are merging just be what is returned. Afterall, in essence you are replacing what is already there with what you are passing

Comment: Because the framework is already managing an instance. It makes more sense to return the existing managed instance than to replace it just so you can continue using the unmanaged instance you were using before. Plus, that managed instance might be referenced elsewhere. When you `merge`, you get the managed instance back (even if it's the same one). The code calling `merge` is aware of this and can act accordingly. But if `merge` worked the way you suggest, then other code that references the managed instance suddenly has an unmanaged instance, which would be surprising.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Let's look at the `persist` case in regards to `save`. In the `persist` case, doesn't `persist` make the passed entity a managed instance? And then you are simply continuing using that managed instance

Comment: Yes, because _persisting_ involves **new** entities. There is no existing managed instance. _Merging_ may update an existing managed instance, in which case it needs to return said already-existing instance.

Comment: gotcha. That makes sense now!